# How to set "hit" tolerance for touch dragging in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, mobile

I have a Openlayers map with a single point feature on. When pressing a button I activate a drag handler.

My problem is when using mobile devices dragging the point is virtually impossible. No matter the settings in the stylemap (size of the feature), you have to hit it exactly on the point.

Is it possible to set a hit tolerance, or create a buffer?

Any alternate solutions is welcome.